# Why does command-with-error | grep 'regex-not-matching-error' still print an error?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash.
 I ran following code and got some output,

```
$ cat non_exist_file | grep -e 'dummy'
  cat: non_exist_file: No such file or directory
```

It was strange for me because I expected the output should have nothing.

I have read a instruction in bash manual below,

```
Pipelines

[time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]
...
If |& is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard output,
is connected  to  command2's  standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand
for 2>&1 |.
```

On the basis instruction above, I expected the pipeline passes the error message,

```
cat: non_exist_file: No such file or directory
```

to the grep as standard input. And the final output will be nothing because any word in the error message does not match. However I got the error message.

What is happened to the code above? I am afraid I made a cheap misunderstanding. Please teach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` only connects *standard output*, but `cat` prints the error message (as expected) to *standard error*.

As the man page says, use `|&` to also connect *standard error* to `grep`'s *standard input*:

```
cat non_exist_file |& grep -e 'dummy'
```

Comment: I did not know |& is a one word. I though it means | and &. Thank you.

Comment: @mora, if they had their original meanings separately, `|` and `&` wouldn't make sense together -- `&` puts the preceding command in the background, but if the command following it in a pipeline is in the foreground, there's no reasonable meaning that the `&` could have, since the following foreground command still needs to wait until it can read its stdin.

Comment: @Charles Duffy : thank you for kind comment. I misunderstood "|& is used" is "| or &" is used. And I did not pay attention to what & part means because I focused on '|'. But anyway it was still my weird misunderstanding... Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

another option with same result as the last answer, this will redirect stderr to stdout

```
cat non_exist_file 2>&1 | grep -e 'dummy'
```